# Installing SCVMM on a VM and use it to manage the hypervisor hosting that VM (for a lab)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v-server-2012, scvmm, system-center

I know this would be unacceptable for a production deployment, but I have only one beefy server I can use for lab test\learning.

Here is what I am planning:

1. Install Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 on the server
2. Spin up a VM
3. Install SCVMM (along with SQL) on this VM
4. Manage the hosting hypervisor from the SCVMM VM

Any caveats to this? Performance will be awful, but I'm OK with that for this lab.

Comment: Why would this be a problem?

Comment: Why will performance be awful?

Comment: Why would this be unacceptable for a production deployment?

Comment: @joeqwerty probably because if the single physical host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common configuration (except with multi-host clusters in production).

Carry on.